# Prevent expressions enclosed in backticks from being evaluated in heredocs

Tags: bash, shell

I have a text like this:

```
foo bar
`which which`
```

If I do this using heredoc, I get a blank file:

```
➜  ~  echo <<EOT > out
heredoc> foo bar
heredoc> `which which`
heredoc> EOT
➜  ~  cat out

➜  ~
```

How can I do this?

#### Edit

Oh sorry, I meant to do `cat`. Problem is that it writes this to the file: `which: shell built-in command`, ie, evaluations backticks. Any way to do this without evaluating?

With `cat`, I get

```
➜  ~  cat <<EOT > out
heredoc> foo bar
heredoc> `which which`
heredoc> EOT
➜  ~  cat out
foo bar
which: shell built-in command
➜  ~
```

I don't want `which which` to be evaluated.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Quote the label to prevent the backticks from being evaluated.

```
$ cat << "EOT" > out
foo bar
`which which`
EOT

$ cat out
foo bar
`which which`
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to do cat. Problem is that it writes this to the file: `which: shell built-in command`, ie, evaluations backticks. Any way to do this without evaluating?

Comment: Quote the label to prevent the backticks from being evaluated.

Comment: FYI this will also disable other bash expression (such as variable evaluation) from occurring. To just disable backtick evaluation you can escape the backticks by adding a backslash, e.g. '\\`'

Comment: Why does this work?? There is no sanity in Bash.

Comment: Here's the relevant documentation on turning off substitution in here doc : http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html#EX71C, so there's 3 options : either `\EOT`, `'EOT'` or `"EOT"`.

Comment: @tsbertalan There's plenty of sanity to this! In heredocs, expressions are evaluated, such as variables being expanded to their value. Backticks are used in shell scripts to represent an expression statement, similar to `$(...)`. To turn off evaulation, you have to use a delimiter that is marked to turn off evaluation, and consistently, `\` is the escape character used to prevent evaluations throughout shell, including heredocs.